# How os dispatch threads and process on cpu

Tags: x86

I am wondering how linux os populates /proc/cpuinfo special file. Is there a cpu instruction that gives the number of cpu and cores ?

Is there an x86 assembly instruction can switch a thread or process on a specific cpu ?

Comment: These are two very different questions. For the second one, the answer is no. The CPU has no concept of threads or processes. The OS is what works with these. I think you are asking about CPU affinity. See http://www.glennklockwood.com/hpc-howtos/process-affinity.html

Comment: Have a look at the [Multiprocessor Specification 1.4](http://www.indocomp.com/biosupdates/mps1-4.pdf). It contains answers for most of your question parts.

Comment: Thanks but can you precise ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BIOS populates the ACPI tables (specifically, the APIC and MADT) with information about the processors in the system. Linux reads these tables to find out how many processors there are.

The processor does have ways to switch a thread or process*, but no modern OS uses them. If you care to, you can read about tasks in the Software Developers Manual (volume 3, section 7).

* Specifically, a far jump or call through a task gate, an iret from a nested task, or an interrupt through a task gate.

Comment: You say no modern os use it but the os should dispatch process itself ?

Comment: @Bob, The OS may start/resume a process using iret, sysexit, or sysret.

Comment: Is there a way to log and see all cpu instruction with virtualbox or kvm for exemple ? I want to understand